# How to lock and unlock VMware or VirtualBox VMs with a fingerprint device?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtualization, fingerprint

Is it possible to lock and unlock VMs in VirtualBox or VMware using a fingerprint device in Linux? I know that VMware's latest versions supports virtual TPM, but i want to encrypt and unlock the entire Virtual Machine content with a FingerPrint device and my host machine is Linux.

Do any of them support this? If not, what is the best way to achieve this? I only want to do this with specific VMs, not all of them.

Comment: What problems do you see in a fingerprint device being used in a VM?

Comment: I want to do this in the worst case scenario where the host is infected by a rootkit and maybe a remote attacker can steal these VMs. A TPM or any other password based encryption is fine but thats just a password and easy to find if they have access to the host itself, but a fingerprint based encryption is much harder (not impossible, but harder)

Comment: TPM is easy to find ??? Microsoft will be disappointed.

Comment: @harrymc Whoops sorry i was talking about VMware's virtual TPM, not a real TPM. That does encrypt the VM, but if they already have access to host then they are probably keylogging, etc and can sniff the password. But again i know they could do the same with a fingerprint device, but obviously that would be way too harder.

Comment: If somebody controls your device, nothing you do will stop them. Fingerprint devices can also be spoofed. If you're worried, store your VMs in a VeraCrypt container. It has multiple protection and unlock schemes.

Comment: In case your hypervisor is compromised, its endgame. No chance to keep any VM secure with any method. If you are **that** concerned about security, have a look into Qubes. If it is just for shits and giggles, have a look into USB passthrough.